# Read a Single String from a File at a Time

Tags: java, string, file, while-loop

```
Abe
Bobby
Joseph
yyvoynne
Kathryn
```

^^ the file i'm reading from. How would I go about reading in one word at a time,assigning that one word to a variable, doing stuff to it, then reading in another name from the file? I'm really just getting stuck on how to assign the word I read in to a variable. Thanks for your time.

```
while(names.hasNext())
        {
            //Stuff

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for reading line by line from file.

You can try this: its a common way to read from files.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
String word;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    word = line;
    //do stuff with word
}
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(names.hasNext())
        {
         String name = names.next(); // Assuming Scanner is used to read file
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
while(names.hasNext()){
    String name = names.next();
    ... do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Path path = Paths.get("names-in-cwd.txt"); /* Relative or absolute path here. */
Charset encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8; /* Or whatever it is really. */
for (String name : Files.readAllLines(path, encoding)) {
  /* Do stuff with value in "name" variable ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and use the [`useDelimiter(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) method to do this:

Make sure you add these imports:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

And then you can do this, using an ArrayList to hold the names.

```
try {
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("yourFileNameAndPath.txt"));
    file.useDelimiter("\\s+"); // split names by any whitespace

    // list is the ArrayList to hold all of the names
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (file.hasNext()) {
        list.add(file.next());
    }

    // print it out to test
    // new element (name) after every ###
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i) + "###");
    }
    print(list.size()); // print number of names found

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

---

With your file, this is the output:

```
Abe###
Bobby###
Joseph###
yyvoynne###
Kathryn###
5
```